# Easy way to read through/visualize a project?

Tags: github, architecture, gitlab, structure, software-design

Trying to read through a huge github repo can be pretty slow and difficult to manage. I find myself opening tons of tabs trying to follow import statements and hierarchies. Are there any tools that help make a project easier to understand?

All I want to do is to read through a repo and understand how a project works (and preferably the code underneath) in the most convenient way possible.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic for SO, but in general I find it is best to clone repositories locally and browse them using an IDE with the tools I need. This is useful because an IDE should (1) have good intellisense features, (2) allow you split windows vertically and horizontally so you can view multiple files together easily and (3) other useful features like locating usages of various symbols. It's also a skill you'll get better at over time. Other than that, hopefully the maintainers provide documentation which always helps, too :-) Hope that helps answer your question.

Comment: That actually seems pretty useful, thanks!